# Uses of :: in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

So before people tell me to googe it, I have and that's why I'm  here.

My question is -

**How is the :: able to be used for things other than constructors?**

I know the correct rule for constructors is that they have to have the same name as the class in which they belong to. But in this code,  it's being used regardless of that. Can someone tell me why and how?

**Edit: I forgot to mention, the first block is a header file and the second is the cpp source to said header.**

---

```
class Rainbow{
public:

    static void registerItems();//Does exactly what it says
    static void initClientData();//Initializes stuff like icon and texture
    static void initCreativeItems();//Adds them to the creative inventory


    static Item* mSword;//This is our item. 
};
```

---

```
void Rainbow::registerItems(){
mSword = new SwordItem(3000);//Add our sword object to our SwordItem class
}

void Rainbow::initClientData(){
mSword->setIcon("rainbow_sword",0);//Sets its icon image
}

void Rainbow::initCreativeItems(){
Item::addCreativeItem(3000,0);//Uses the ID to add it to the creative inventory
}
```

Comment: Can :: be used for things other than constructors?  - yes it can. A constructor is just a method.

Comment: All 4 uses of `::` in your question have nothing to do with constructors. You don't even have any constructors here...

Comment: You are talking about the scope resolution operator.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's why I'm asking this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::` symbol is used whenever a given name is to be found inside another named thing, but the containing thing is not an object (but is a class, namespace, or enumeration).

```
namespace n {
    struct s {
        enum e {
            q
        };
    };
}

n::s::e my_value = n::s::e::q;
```

It is left-associative, so in this case `e` is found inside `n::s` and `q` is inside `n::s::e`.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the scope resolution operator (::). It is used to depict scope.

```
int a=5;   //Global Variable

int main() {
     int a=1;  //local variable
     cout<<a;
     cout<<::a;  //We are explicitly mentioning that we need the global scope 'a' variable
     return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 1
>      5

A constructor is just a method, you can make your own methods to initialize date members. A constructor (Same name as the Class) is called automatically when an object is created.

Normally, a default constructor would be called to initialize the objects upon creation, this is automatic.
Then you can explicitly call your methods to set values for the data members you wish.

For the correct explanation for your case, look at the top comment on this answer

Comment: In the given example, the default constructor is trivial, so it's *not* called. The member is static, so not created, initialized, or uninitialized. The methods modify a global variable.